# How do I remove an object nested in two arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I want to have a function that receives the name of the category and the name of one of the items of that category and returns the entire object without that item, how do I do that?

This is what I have so far, I managed to find the item I want to delete with two loops but I don't know how to delete it.

```
const removeItem = (categoryName, itemName) => {
    const data = loadAll()
    data.categories.forEach(category => {
        if(category.name === categoryName){
            category.items.forEach(item => {
                if(item.name === itemName){
                    // DELETE
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Object:

```
{
   "categories":[
      {
         "name":"Carne",
         "items":[
            {
               "name":"Bitoque",
               "price":10
            },
            {
               "name":"Bife",
               "price":8
            },
            {
               "name":"Frango Grelhado",
               "price":6
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"Peixe",
         "items":[
            {
               "name":"Dourada",
               "price":12
            },
            {
               "name":"Sardinhas",
               "price":8
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"Entradas",
         "items":[
            {
               "name":"Couvert",
               "price":2
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"Sumos",
         "items":[

         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Dear Daniel, please ask an specific problem.

Comment: I added the code I have

Comment: Have you tried `delete item.name;` where you have `//DELETE`?

Comment: FFFS another "question" about data structures that can be answered by saying "use the functionality that data structures give you".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to just `filter` the `items`, e.g.

```
const removeItem = (categoryName, itemName) => {
     const data = loadAll()
     data.categories.forEach(category => {
          if(category.name === categoryName){
              category.items = category.items.filter(item => item.name !== itemName);
          }
     });
}
```